# Animating WrapPanel Children on Resize

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, panel, expression-blend

I am not necessarily new to WPF, but I am very new to WPF Animations. I want to make the children of my WrapPanel animate whenever they are being repositioned. I found [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dancre/archive/2006/02/23/537966.aspx) article, but it makes the window resize **extremely** choppy at best. I assume this is because the code is not is not inside of the WrapPanel ArrangeOverride itself. Any suggestions?

**Edit**
I have now also attempted the AnimatedWrapPanel as described [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/153554/Animated-WPF-Panels). Once again, it works, but it is so harsh on the video rendering that it is very slow. There has to be a way to do this without it being so process intensive...

Comment: There is a control in the [WPF Bag of Tricks](https://github.com/thinkpixellab/bot) That already does this. Check it out.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in another direction HighCore. I am not in a position to build the Github solution at the moment, but it looks promising and I will let you know how it goes.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a perfect job for `FluidMoveBehavior` to make it quick and easy. You can find more info on the net or even an older article like [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/expression/ff624123.aspx). From what you're asking it sounds like just what you're looking for and a really painless way to accomplish it. Hope this helps.

Comment: The link is dead unfortunately.

Comment: @DrewNoakes yea well even MSFT can deserve some grace for something from 2013, but there's still lots of stuff found with a quick google. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 0):

I was able to accomplish what I needed and more by utilizing some of the code from the WPF Spark `FluidWrapPanel`. This can be found [here](https://github.com/ratishphilip/wpfspark). There are also some other great controls that I am utilizing from that library as well. Thanks for your help everyone.